# Don't delete AppSettings not declared in a template

Tags: azure, appsettings, azure-rm-template

When deploying an **Azure Function App** and **AppSettings** via an **ARM Template**, is it possible to tell Azure not to delete **AppSettings** that are not declared in the template?

For example, take the following **AppSettings** config from the template and imagine that I'm updating an existing **Function App**.  In this case, an **AppSetting** called **storageaccountname_STORAGE** would be deleted, which is undesirable as (for example) it has been created to facilitate a binding.

```
{
    "apiVersion":"2016-08-01",
    "name":"appsettings",
    "type":"config",
    "dependsOn":[
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites/Slots', variables('functionAppName'), 'Staging')]"
    ],
    "properties":{
        "AzureWebJobsStorage":"[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1, ';')]",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard":"[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1, ';')]",
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY":"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2014-04-01').InstrumentationKey]",
        "FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE":"readwrite",
        "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION":"~1",
        "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING":"[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listkeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1, ';')]",
        "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE":"[toLower(variables('functionAppName'))]",
        "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION":"6.5.0"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to selectivly set **AppSettings** via an **ARM Template**, or are the templates simply not capale of functioning as desired for such a scenario?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem also a while ago and did not find a solution within an ARM Template.

In my case I solved it by using a PowerShell Script what run after the ARM Template.
Maybe you can use some parts of this:

https://gist.github.com/kirkone/2b5996a57a5610a8a41e2bfd1edc37f1

The main part is getting the current values, add or override with the new values and write back the complete list.
This Script is for use with VSTS / TFS but it should give you a hint about how it can be done.

Sorry for not having a better solution but I hope this helps also.

CU
KirK

Comment: We're doing something similar at the moment, although we must first pull all AppSettings, fire off the ARM Template, and them update/push only the settings that are not in the ARM Template.  To be honest it's a bit of a faff, so hopefully MS come up with a better solution for this in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: Go vote!

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/31985941-no-parity-between-function-app-and-web-app-app-set